# how to set id to Html.TextBox item on MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox, html.textbox

Im trying to catch the textbox element by javascript, in order to put text into it. 
so how to set id to the textbox ??

```
        <tr>
                    // Id to this textbox
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.OperationNo)</td>
        </tr>
```

and then to put text into it by JS

```
                            // 
   document.getElementById("Textbox id").Text= " Some text " ;
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can set ID of a textbox like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.OperationNo, new { id = "MyId" })
```

OR

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.OperationNo, htmlAttributes: new { id = "MyId" })
```

### Output:

```
<input ... id="MyId" name="OperationNo" type="text" />
```

Comment: This is overriding the default id which will match the name of the property.

Answer (score 8):

**You can use below code for resolve that problem:**

```
function steVal() {
        document.getElementById('txtPlace').value = "Set The Text";
    }

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OperationNo,new { @id = "txtPlace",@name="txtPlace" })
```

Comment: You don't need the "@" signs in front of the property names in your anonymous class. The only time you need to do it is when the property name happens to be a reserved word, such as "class".

Comment: I gave this one a thumbs up because it showed how to do more than one attribute, which is what I was looking for. :o)

Answer (score 5):

It should be the property name, which is `OperationNo`.

So your JS will be

```
document.getElementById("OperationNo").html = " Some text " ;
```

You can use the web inspector in Chrome or JS to view the html on your page to see the element attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens in a scenario of using same input fields with same properties in web form. Like the case of Login and Signup forms in single view/page.
    Previously it was like this

input one >

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control",placeholder = "Username", @required = "required", autofocus = "" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

input two>

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", @required = "required", autofocus = "" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

then i added a unique id # for the username input

the new input one >

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", id = "loginUsername", placeholder = "Username", @required = "required", autofocus = "" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

the new input two >

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", id = "SignupUsername" , placeholder = "Username", @required = "required", autofocus = "" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```